# CPP undefined reference to 'Myclass::Myclass()' using codeblocks

Tags: c++

So I am currently studying CPP, I am using Codeblocks and when I am attempting to create a constructor and a deconstructor with a class using separate files I keep getting the error

```
||=== Build: Debug in 1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cclh2esZ.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\1\1\main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `Myclass::Myclass()'|
C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\1\1\main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `Myclass::~Myclass()'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

and here is the code that i am using to get this error

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Myclass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    Myclass obj;
}
```

`Myclass.h`

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H


class Myclass
{
    public:
        Myclass();
        ~Myclass();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

`Myclass.cpp`

```
#include "Myclass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Myclass::Myclass()
{
   cout << "constructor"<< endl; //ctor
}

Myclass::~Myclass()
{
    cout << "deconstructor" << endl;
}
```

Please help me, I have been stuck for over a day now and I can really need the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: can  you possibly demonstrate the difference?

Comment: @vishal *include main.cpp code into Myclass.cpp* and get laughed out of your next job interview.

Comment: @nm i know it is not the correct way!,

Comment: @vishal so don't suggest it.

Comment: compile using: `g++ main.cpp Myclass.cpp` in the terminal

Comment: :/ I can already feel the love

Comment: Compile `g++ MyClass.cpp MyClass.h main.cpp -o myprogram` on the Terminal and then run `myprogram`

Comment: This link would surely help you in some way. http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think would cause this kind of problem would be a linking error.

If you go under the File tab, then select class, and go through the window prompts, and it should automatically create and link a header and source file.

If you want to link your files manually you can add the path to the folder the file is within, under the tab Project, then Build Options, then Search directories. Any addresses you add to the compiler and and linker will be searched when the compiler looks for an #include.

Comment: which is something that would need to be done through the code block interface correct?

Comment: Correct. The tabs mentioned above are at the top of the codeblocks window.

Comment: cause it all looks ok to me

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Myclass.h"
#include "Myclass.cpp" // You forgot to reference this class.

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    Myclass obj;
}
```

You forgot line #3.